# Revertir acciones en un fragmento Android Studio - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, kotlin, onbackpressed

Estoy esquematizando un fragmento en donde realizo algunos cambios al hacer click en un botón, mi fragmento es de la siguiente forma:

```js
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtFirstDirection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Buscar aquí:"
        android:textColor="@color/evans_black1"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_style_white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnNextDirection"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/square_black_icon"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/originDirection"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:text="Jr. Revolución 416, puno"
                android:textColor="@color/evans_black1"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNextDirection"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_black_style"
        android:text="Siguiente"
        android:textColor="@color/evansWhite"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Al Hacer click en en botón estoy realizando cambios y ocultado el **TextView** del fragmento y cambiando  también el primer **TextView** de la siguiente forma:

```js
btnNextDirection.setOnClickListener{
  txtFirstDirection.text = "Nueva palabra"
  originDirection.visibility = View.GONE
}
```

Tengo una duda, ¿Cómo puedo revertir esos cambios con onBackPressed?¿Se podría? Vi que algunas app's lo hacen o existe alguna forma de regresar al estado inicial. Si alguien me podría ayudar le agradecería de antemano

Comment: Crea un método privado, por ejemplo "resetView()" y dentro pon qué estado debe tener la vista por defecto.  Después en onBackPressed() llama a ese método.  Si sólo quieres revertir al estado anterior y no hay uno por defecto en la vista, prueba a crear un objeto formado por varios atributos con el estado de la vista actual, inicialmente será null.  Cuando necesites hacer un revert, recupera el estado anterior.  Hay un patrón de diseño llamado Memento que en este segundo caso te podría venir bien.

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres volver al estado incial de la actividad puedes usar el método recreate() de la siguiente forma

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    //Volver al estado inicial
    recreate();
}
```